# Error searching for data in sqlite database

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

So, I wanna search for a value inside my database (sqlite on android), and to do so I'm using this method :

```
public Stuff search(Stuff stuff) {
String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_STUFF + " WHERE NOME = " + stuff.getNome();

Cursor cursor = this.database.rawQuery(sql, null);

Stuff tempStuff = new Stuff(
        //cursor.getLong(0),
        cursor.getString(1)
);

if (tempStuff == null)
    return null;
else
    return tempStuff;

}
```

My stuff.getNome() is "sports". When I run the query, I get this error:

```
07-11 08:34:42.099 26595-26595/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: sports
07-11 08:34:42.101 26595-26595/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-11 08:34:42.108 26595-26595/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.nelsu.idk, PID: 26595
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nelsu.idk/com.example.nelsu.idk.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Sports(code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM STUFF WHERE NOME = Sports
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Sports(code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM STUFF WHERE NOME = Sports
```

It's searching by the column name and not by the data inside it, right? Why?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `WHERE NOME = "Sports"` ?

Comment: May you show us the create query ?

Comment: @B001ᛦ no, but I want it to be generic, I don't want just to search for one value, I want to search for whatever comes from .getNome();

Comment: _I don't want just to search for one value.._ I am aware of that... I meant to use double quotes `""`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A value needs to be put inside double quotes. Change your query to

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_STUFF + " WHERE NOME = \"" + stuff.getNome() + "\"";
```

Comment: yeah, it was it, thanks ! and also thanks for the downvotes, whoever did them !

Comment: This is wrong; strings should  be enclosed in single quotes (see https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html under "Literal values").

Comment: @varro: this is not wrong. Bother are correct. BTW best approach is parameters, read about them.